# Data lost when trying to edit record

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm currently having this issue:  I have 3 tables: users, roles and users_roles as in the picture below:

[image: EER]

whenever I edit any of the record in **users** table, the record of that user in the users_roles table will be lost.
For example, I changed the username of the user which holds the userId = 2, then in the users_roles table, the row of userId = 2 will be lost.

Anybody has any ideas of this problem? I'm using Spring with Hibernate

*UPDATE

In my Role.java

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "roles")
private List<User> users;
```

In my User.java

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId", nullable = false) , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "roleId", nullable = false) )
    private List<Role> roles;
```

And in my UsersRoles.java

```
@Id
@Column(name="userId")
private int userId;

@Id
@Column(name="roleId")
private int roleId;
```

This is the DAO implementation method I used for Edit

```
@Override
public void edit(User user) {
session.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(user);
}
```

P/S: this not only happens when I edit with my web-app, but also happens when I edit directly in MySQL environment. I don't know...

Comment: Please, post the mappings and the code which you use to edit the user.

Comment: Seems like unusual behavior.  Are there any triggers in the database?

Comment: I have uploaded my code to Drive, you guys can have a look at: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6leBI3z6ye6OGpQZUxiOVo4NE0&usp=sharing

Comment: you guys can try login as id: admin, pass: admin.  Thanks in advance